# Django docker: docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed

Tags: python, django, docker

I want to deploy my django project with docker and uwsgi on windows 11, but get some errors.

```
docker build . -t djangohw
docker run -it --rm djangohw -p 8080:80
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-p": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV DEPLOY=1
WORKDIR /opt/tmp
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["sh", "start.sh"]
```

**start.sh**

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations board
python3 manage.py migrate
uwsgi --module=mysite.wsgi:application \
    --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings \
    --master \
    --http=0.0.0.0:0 \
    --processes=5 \
    --harakiri=20 \
    --max-requests=5000 \
    --vacuum
```

**requirements.txt**

```
django==4.1.3
django-cors-headers
pytest
pytest-django
coverage
uwsgi
```

Comment: How are you actually running the container?  (Have you possibly tried to put a `docker run -p 12345:6789` option after the `docker run image-name`, causing it to be interpreted as the command to run rather than a Docker option?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-p [hostPort]:{containerPort}` should be placed in front of the image name, otherwise it will be regarded as a command to run when the container starts

`docker run -it --rm -p 8080:80 djangohw` should be correct.